# "No operating system" after installing new hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-vista, windows-installation

I bought a laptop from eBay. The previous owner took the hard drive out, so I replaced it with a new hard drive.

I installed the new hard drive, did a hard drive self test – it passed.

I downloaded a Windows Vista driver and put CD in drive; it still says "no operating system".

Comment: In the future please [edit] your question to include more info. Thanks.

Comment: Without knowing the brand and model of the laptop you will get only generic *Change BIOS settings to boot from CD* answers.

Answer (score 1):

First in Bios you need to set the primary boot device as your CD-Drive.

Right now the Bios tries to load OS from your hard-drive-which has no Operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Setup your BIOS. Make it start from CD-ROM.